# Fixing column names with unnest_wider in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am having a problem in R and seek your help!

I have a tibble that looks like this (unfortunately, I can't figure out how to write the code to create the table here). My table looks exactly like this to the viewer, e.g., you can see the letter "c" in the table.

```
person     zip_code
Laura      c("11001", "28720", "32948", "10309")
Mel        c("80239", "23909")
Jake       c("20930", "23929", "13909")
```

In short, my "zip_code" column contains rows of character vectors, each of which contain multiple ZIP codes.

I would like to separate the column "zip_code" into multiple columns, each containing one zip code (e.g., "zip_code_1", "zip_code_2", etc.). To do so, I have been using `unnest_wider`:

```
unnest_wider(zip_code, names_sep="_")
```

However, whenever I do this, the names of the new columns generated by `unnest_wider` come out wrong. Instead of being "zip_code_1", "zip_code_2", "zip_code_3," the new names are "zip_code_1[,1]", "zip_code_2[,1]", and zip_code_3[,1]". Basically, each column name has a "[,1]" afterward.

I have not repeated these column names anywhere, so I have no idea why they look like this.

I cannot manually rename them with:

```
dplyr::rename(zip_code_1=`zip_code_[,1]`)
```

If I do this, I get an error message.

Any help fixing these names is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is your `zip_code` column the literal string `"c(\"11001\", \"28720\", ...)"`, or is it a "real" column of individual strings? To remove ambiguity, it helps to share in an unambiguous format, the gold-standard being `dput(head(zip_code))` (paste its output into a code block). Thanks!

Comment: Can you share an example with the exact data structure using `dput`?

Comment: @Axeman Here is the result from doing dput(head(mydata$zip_code)): list(structure(c("11374", "11374"), .Dim = 2:1), structure(c("10023", 
"10023"), .Dim = 2:1), structure(c("10028", "10028"), .Dim = 2:1), 
    structure(c("11210", "12498", "11210", "12498"), .Dim = c(4L, 
    1L)), structure(c("10301", "10301"), .Dim = 2:1), structure(c("12524", 
    "10605", "12524", "10605"), .Dim = c(4L, 1L)))

Comment: I thought you said you had a `tibble`, this is just a `list` of single-column `matrix` objects. When you are able to share the tibble itself, please [edit] your question and put it there, comments are easily skipped by readers and/or hidden by the interface.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, it is a single column matrix, convert to a vector and it should work `df1 %>% mutate(zip = map(zip, c)) %>% unnest_wider(zip, names_sep = "_")`

Comment: FYI, for questions that involve tibbles/frames, it's generally best to provide the `dput` of a tibble/frame, not of a single column. I understand and appreciate the preference to subset your data to just what is needed, but in questions like this, please subset down to a single-column frame at a minimum, not its vector/list. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the OP's data, it is a case of `matrix` column, thus if we convert to a vector (doesn't have `dim` attributes), the `names_sep` should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(zip = map(zip, c)) %>% 
   unnest_wider(zip, names_sep = "_")
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  zip_1 zip_2 zip_3 zip_4
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 10010 10019 10010 10019
2 10019 10032 10019 10032
3 11787 11375 11787 11375
```

---

Or as @IceCreamToucan mentioned, the `transform` option in `unnest_wider` would make it concise

```
unnest_wider(df1, zip, names_sep = '_', transform = c)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  zip_1 zip_2 zip_3 zip_4
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 10010 10019 10010 10019
2 10019 10032 10019 10032
3 11787 11375 11787 11375
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(zip = list(structure(c("10010", "10019", "10010", 
"10019"), dim = c(4L, 1L)), structure(c("10019", "10032", "10019", 
"10032"), dim = c(4L, 1L)), structure(c("11787", "11375", "11787", 
"11375"), dim = c(4L, 1L)))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest, pivot_wider
dat %>%
  mutate(
    # because your sample data didn't have an ID-column
    person = LETTERS[row_number()],
    # it's better to work with list-columns of strings, not matrices
    zip_code = lapply(zip_code, c)
  ) %>%
  unnest(zip_code) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(rn = paste0("zip", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(person, names_from = "rn", values_from = "zip_code") %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   person zip1  zip2  zip3  zip4 
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 A      11374 11374 NA    NA   
# 2 B      10023 10023 NA    NA   
# 3 C      10028 10028 NA    NA   
# 4 D      11210 12498 11210 12498
# 5 E      10301 10301 NA    NA   
# 6 F      12524 10605 12524 10605
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(zip_code = list(structure(c("11374", "11374"), .Dim = 2:1), structure(c("10023", "10023"), .Dim = 2:1), structure(c("10028", "10028"), .Dim = 2:1), structure(c("11210", "12498", "11210", "12498"), .Dim = c(4L, 1L)), structure(c("10301", "10301"), .Dim = 2:1), structure(c("12524", "10605", "12524", "10605"), .Dim = c(4L, 1L)))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! For some reason I keep getting this error code:

Comment: Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ungroup()
  4. plyr::mutate(., rn = paste0("zip", row_number()))
  5. [ base::eval(...) ] with 1 more call
  8. dplyr::row_number()
  9. dplyr::n()
 10. dplyr:::peek_mask("n")
 11. dplyr:::context_peek("mask", fun)

Comment: Do you see that you're using `plyr` instead of `dplyr`? Stop loading `plyr`, or if you must load it, load it *before* `dplyr`. Try to unload both and reload in order, `detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE); detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE); library(plyr); library(dplyr)` (or omit `library(plyr)` if you don't explicitly know you need it loaded).

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for the advice; I will omit plyr in the future!

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I just got this solution to work for me as well!